# Поворот после окончания анимации бега

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    const string IDLE = "m_idle_A";
    const string WALK = "m_run";

    CustomAction input;

    NavMeshAgent agent;
    Animator animator;

    [Header("Movement")]
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem clickEffect; // Эффект клика для визуализации нажатия
    [SerializeField] LayerMask clickableLayers;   // Слой, по которому можно кликать для перемещения

    float lookRotationSpeed = 8f; // Скорость поворота игрока

    void Awake()
    {
        // Получаем ссылки на компоненты при запуске
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>(); // Компонент управления навигацией
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();   // Аниматор персонажа

        // Настройка пользовательского ввода
        input = new CustomAction();
        AssigInputs();
    }

    void AssigInputs()
    {
        // Привязываем метод ClickToMove к событию "перемещения" пользовательского ввода
        input.Main.Move.performed += ctx => ClickToMove();
    }

    void ClickToMove()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 100, clickableLayers))
        {
            // Задаем точку назначения для навигационного агента
            agent.destination = hit.point;

            // Воспроизводим эффект клика, если он указан
            if (clickEffect != null)
            {
                Instantiate(clickEffect, hit.point += new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0), clickEffect.transform.rotation);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        // Включаем пользовательский ввод при активации объекта
        input.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        // Выключаем пользовательский ввод при деактивации объекта
        input.Disable();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        FaceTarget();      // Вызываем метод для поворота персонажа в сторону цели
        SetAnimations();   // Вызываем метод для управления анимациями
    }

    void FaceTarget()
    {
        // Определяем направление к цели и плавно поворачиваем персонажа в эту сторону
        Vector3 direction = (agent.destination - transform.position).normalized;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * lookRotationSpeed);
    }

    void SetAnimations()
    {
        // Управляем анимациями в зависимости от скорости движения агента
        if (agent.velocity == Vector3.zero)
        {
            animator.Play(IDLE);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.Play(WALK);
        }
    }
}
```

Именно после окончания бега начинается анимация idle, во время которой игрок поворачивается.

Comment: Здорово. А в чём вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что при окончании анимации бега, включается анимация idle и игрок поворачивается, хотя в анимации данное действие не задано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему.
Добавил проверку -

```
void FaceTarget()
{
    Vector3 direction = agent.destination - transform.position;
    
    if (direction != Vector3.zero)
    {
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * lookRotationSpeed);
    }
}
```